# Export Adobe Illustrator draw project

Tags: adobe-illustrator, ipad, adobe-draw

I want to know how can I move my project in Adobe Illustrator draw from my iPad to my Computer's Adobe Illustrator with all vectors intact.

I've tried but all I get is a jpeg file without the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

To send a drawing from iPad to Illustrator you have to tap on the Share button and then on Send to Illustrator CC.

To make the transfer work you must be signed with the same Adobe account on both Illustrator Draw and Illustrator CC.

In this [tutorial](https://helpx.adobe.com/mobile-apps/how-to/vector-drawing-go.html) you can probably find why this didn't work.